# XCode 6 Beta will overwrite XCode 5.1.1?

Tags: xcode5.1, xcode6, ios8

I am about to install XCode 6 Beta and it asked to close the already running XCode 5.1.1.

Will it overwrite XCode 5.1.1,O or will XCode 6 be a separate installation?

Comment: It shouldn't override it only the full version should override, it hasn't in the past anyway but I can't remember if it will replace as the default application when it opens projects up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a different installation.

It was the first time that XCode asked for installation after coping it to the Applications folder. Usually, after coping XCode from its .dmg file, I rename it and runs it.

[image]

I have several XCode versions in my Applications folder. I got confused when it asked to close the existing XCode 5.1.1 during installation, since it never happened before.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has a different name: Xcode6-Beta rather than the normal Xcode.

[image: Screenshot of Applications folder under OSX 10.10]

Comment: Naming does not make any sense. But it was asking for installation after I double clicked on its icon. Usually XCode just open on its icon click.

Comment: @VaibhavSaran That's not "installation" which is simply to copy it to `/Applications`.  What you were referring to is setting-up of the developer components etc.